# Add-AzureADGroupMember erroring, message shows extra forward slash

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, azureportal

I'm running the following command:

```
 Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId <Guid1> -RefObjectId <Guid2>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Add-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The URI 'https://graph.windows.net//<tenantId>/directoryObjects/<Guid2>' is not valid since it is not based on 'https://graph.windows.net/<tenantId>/'.
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Note that the first URL has an extra forward slash before the tenant ID.

I believe this is a bug, but not sure.

### Update

I ran the same PowerShell from my local machine and it worked as expected -- this is likely an issue with the version of the AzureAD module that runs in the Azure Portal Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems makes sense. I test it on my side, it works fine from my local machine.

Then I catch the request of the powershell via [**Fiddler**](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), the correct format of the URL should be like the screenshot.

[image]

When I test it in the azure cloud shell, I reproduced your issue.

[image]

And I could not catch the request via fiddler, it seems not post a request.  I think it may be a bug of azure cloud shell. You could open a issue in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=).